# how to add custom controls in MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i am new to iphone i don't know 
how to implement custom control in MPMoviePlayerViewController,
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use MPMoviePlayerController's view to add anything on top of the Video

Like

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;// initialize the MPMoviePlayerController with URL 
UILable *lable = [[UILable alloc] init];
lable.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,200);
[moviePlayerController.view addSubview:lable];
[lable release];
```